# Scraping g2a[dot]com with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to scrape this game website (g2a[dot]com) to get a list of best prices for the games I'm looking for. The prices are usually inside a table (see image).

[image: g2a printscreen]

My code to get to the table is:

```
for gTitle in gameList:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.g2a.com/%s.html' %gTitle).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('table',class_='mp-user-rating')
```

But when I print the table, I find that python has merged all tables in the website together without any of the contents:

```
>>> <table class="mp-user-rating jq-wh-offers wh-table"></table>
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm using python 3.6.1 with BeautifulSoup4 and urllib. I would like to continue using these if possible, but I'm open to change.

Comment: What you need is generated with javascript, you cannot get it using bs. Consider using selenium https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suggested by Pedro, I've tried Selenium and indeed it got the task done. Thank you Pedro! For those who are interested, my code:

```
# importing packages
from selenium import webdriver

# game list
gameList = ['mass-effect-andromeda-origin-cd-key-preorder-global',\
            'total-war-warhammer-steam-cd-key-preorder-global',\
            'starcraft-2-heart-of-the-swarm-cd-key-global-1']

# scraping
chromePath = r"C:\Users\userName\Documents\Python\chromedriver.exe"
for gTitle in gameList:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromePath)
    driver.get('http://www.g2a.com/%s.html' %gTitle)
    table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="about-game"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody""")
    bestPrice = ''.join(list(table.text.split('\n'))[2][12:][:6])
    bestPrice = float(bestPrice.replace(",","."))
    print(bestPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the website. It loads list of games when you click on "LOAD MORE" and henceforth. If you look into the network tab of your browser while inside inspect element and filter only the "xhr" requests you can see the api endpoint it is hitting to load new set of games. I have used this api endpoint as my url.

```
import requests,json
pageNum = 0 # start with 0, (Also using lower than 0 will start it from 0)
while True :
    url = "https://www.g2a.com/lucene/search/filter?&minPrice=0.00&maxPrice=10000&cn=&kr=&stock=all&event=&platform=0&search=&genre=0&cat=0&sortOrder=popularity+desc&start={}&rows=12&steam_app_id=&steam_category=&steam_prod_type=&includeOutOfStock=&includeFreeGames=false&_=1492758607443".format(str(pageNum))

    games_list = json.loads(requests.get(url).text)['docs'] # `games_list` contains each game as a dictionary from where you can take out the required information.  

    if len(games_list) == 0:
        break # we break off here when the maximum of start parameter is reached and the games_list is empty.
    else:
        pageNum += 12 # we use an increment of 12 because we observed an increment of 12 in the start parameter each time we click on "LOAD MORE"
```